# Pix4D Initial process merge looks exploded on one end

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, 3d-map, pix4d

I have a 3700+ image project that has been merged from 9 separate projects. After the final merge, one end of the property looks like it exploded from the ground. If I click on the pixels they show up as images on the side window. Only the 1st initial process has been run, no point cloud or mesh has been created yet, nor have I reoptimized.

Suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of initial process error]

Answer (score 1):

After merging your seperate projects make sure you use the GCP's to increase the overall accuracy then Re-optimize them. And if that doesn't work I would re-run step 1 after implementing the GCP's.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to turn on “Use Geometrically Verified Matching”.  You will need to turn on/click “Advanced” tab and then look for Use Geometrically Verified Matching under the Matching tab.